# How to receive Image URL in getExtra and set it

Tags: android

I have a List Item, on click of which I want to pass Image as "putExtra" and get it in Another Activity using "getExtra". There are similar questions in Stackoverflow which describes few solution but none of it is working for me.

First Activity:

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) {
                intent.putExtra("imageurl", elementList.get(position).getImage());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

When I retrieve it in second activity, i get nothing. It gives error saying:

```
E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https:/tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2017/05/battlefield-africa-sponsored.png?w=764&h=400&crop=1 (No such file or directory)
```

Second Activity:

```
image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
myUri = Uri.parse(b.getString("imageurl"));
image.setImageURI(myUri);
```

How do i overcome it

Comment: what the `elementList.get(position).getImage()` return ?

Comment: It returns string URL : like this : ""https://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2017/05/battlefield-africa-sponsored.png?w=764&h=400&crop=1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the exception source: `java.io.FileNotFoundException`.

If you set a breakpoint in `ImageView#setImageURI`, the `Uri` you specified will lead you to `BitmapFactory#decodeFile`:

```
public static Bitmap decodeFile(String pathName, Options opts) {
  Bitmap bm = null;
  InputStream stream = null;
  try {
    stream = new FileInputStream(pathName); 
    bm = decodeStream(stream, null, opts);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    /*  do nothing.
        If the exception happened on open, bm will be null.
    */
    Log.e("BitmapFactory", "Unable to decode stream: " + e);
  } finally {
    if (stream != null) {
      try {
        stream.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        // do nothing here
      }
    }
  }
  return bm;
}
```

From the above, the issue is obvious - `Uri` is expected to be a file path and yours is not, hence the `java.io.FileNotFoundException` exception. You’ll have to load your Bitmap differently; I’d recommend [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).